# how to retrieve from firebase storage synchronously

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

I have a firebase database which contains nodes of elements which also contain array of firebase storage locations which are images. in my web app I'm trying to retrieve those images. following is the my code.

```
var downUrl;
for(var ob in arrdata){
    var elem = document.createElement("img");
    elem.style.width = "200px";
    elem.style.height = "200px";
    elem.setAttribute("id",snapshot.child(ob).child("imagepaths").val()[0]);
    //List element's property setting
    var model =snapshot.child(ob).child("mobile").child("model").val();
    var imgPath = snapshot.child(ob).child("imagepaths").val()[0];
    var price = snapshot.child(ob).child("price").val();
    var manu = snapshot.child(ob).child("mobile").child("manufacturer").val();
    //End of List element's property setting
    console.log(model);
    storage.refFromURL(imgPath).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
        downUrl = url;
        elem.setAttribute("src",downUrl);
        var contentString = "<li> <span class='mdl-list__item-primary-content'>" +
                            elem.outerHTML+"<span>"+manu+" "+model+"</span>" +
                            "<span class='mdl-list__item-sub-title'>"+price+"</span>" +
                            "</span>" +
                            "</li>";
        console.log(snapshot.child(ob).child("mobile").child("manufacturer").val());
        $("#addList").append(contentString);
    })
}
```

My problem is it's always showing the same content for model, price and manu. I think the reason for this is issue is retrieving images is asynchronous so it replaces the same last retrieved content for model,price and manu. How can I overcome this? is there a way to do this synchronously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.then` is asynchronous which means that once it runs it only pulls the last model, price, and menu values. One solution would be to call a function and pass each of those values in for each iteration of your loop. Then inside that function run your image lookup. This will create a closure over the values which saves them until used by the asynchronous call.

```
function addHTML(imgPath,model,price,menu){
  storage.refFromURL(imgPath).getDownloadURL().then((url) => {
    var downUrl = url;
    elem.setAttribute("src",downUrl);
    var contentString = "<li > <span class='mdl-list__item-primary-content'>"+
    elem.outerHTML+
    "<span>"+manu+" "+model+"</span>"+
     "<span class='mdl-list__item-sub-title'>"+price+"</span>"+
     "</span>"+
    "</li>";
     $("#addList").append(contentString);
  })
}
```

Comment: Worked the solution. Always think simple .. thanks a lot